# Custom Joomla 1.5 View cannot find the layout default.php file

Tags: joomla1.5

I have been developing templates for Joomla 1.5 (obsolete one, yes I knew it. Unfortunately, I've been spending some time working with it and move on to newer version will be like starting from zero).

I tried to understand how Joomla 1.5 components work, especially for those using MVC principle, and somehow I managed to make things work, except now I have been stuck with the layout of a customized view. For unknown reason, Joomla could not read or find the layout (default.php) inside the folder com_hello2/views/viewed/tmpl and give '500 error Layout default not found'.

I tried to move the default.php file from folder to folder, looking if I could figure out where Joomla want me to put the default.php. It DOES work for the default view, located on com_hello2/views/hello2/tmpl.

Could anyone please help me with this problem?

Here are the codes from the controllers:

```
 <?php
 defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
 jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
 class Hello2Controller extends JController
 {

function display($tpl = null)
    {
    $task = JRequest::getVar('task', null, 'default', 'cmd');
    switch ($task){
        case 'view':
        $model = &$this->getModel('Viewed');
        $view = &$this->getView('viewed','html');
        $mylayout = 'default';
        break;
        case 'newstatus':
        break;
        default:
        $view = &$this->getView('hello2','html');
        $model = &$this->getModel();
        $mylayout = 'default';
        break;
    }

    $view->setModel($model,true);
    $view->setLayout($mylayout);
    $view->display();
    }
 }
 ?>
```

I created two models, one is the default Hello2ModelHello2, the new one is Hello2ModelViewed. I seperated the two models based on the tasks in the controllers.

the Hello2ModelHello2:

```
<?php

 // Check to ensure this file is included in Joomla!
  defined('_JEXEC') or die( 'Restricted access' );

 jimport('joomla.application.component.model');

class Hello2ModelHello2 extends JModel
{
   //add CC 
    function getComments()
    {   
    global $mainframe;
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $id = JRequest::getVar('id', 0, '', 'int');
    $query = 'SELECT a.*'.
            ' FROM #__hello1 AS a '.
            ' LEFT JOIN #__content AS b ON a.article_id = b.id'.
            ' WHERE a.state = 1';
    $db->setQuery( $query );
    $comments = $db->loadObjectList();
    return $comments;
    }
}
?>
```

now the Hello2ModelViewed

```
<?php

// Check to ensure this file is included in Joomla!
defined('_JEXEC') or die( 'Restricted access' );
jimport('joomla.application.component.model');
class Hello2ModelViewed extends JModel
{
        function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $id = JRequest::getVar('id', 0, '', 'int');
    $this->setId((int)$id);
}

function setId($id)
{
    // Set new article ID and wipe data
    $this->_id      = $id;
    $this->_article = null;
}


//get certain comment only.
function getSingle()
{
    global $mainframe;
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $id = JRequest::getVar('id', 0, '', 'int');
    $query = 'SELECT a.*'.
            ' FROM #__hello1 AS a' .
            ' LEFT JOIN #__content AS b ON a.article_id = b.id'.
            ' WHERE a.id = '.$id.
            ' AND a.state = 1';
    $db->setQuery( $query );
    $comments = $db->loadObjectList();
return $comments;
}
}
?>
```

the view.html of Viewed View is

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die( 'Restricted access' );
jimport( 'joomla.application.component.view');
jimport('joomla.environment.request');

class Hello2View extends JView
{
     function __construct($config = array())
     {
    parent::__construct($config);
     } 
 }
class Hello2ViewViewed extends Hello2View{
function display($tpl = null)
{
$model = &$this->getModel(); 
$id = JRequest::getVar('id', 0, '', 'int'); 
$comments = $model->getSingle();
JRequest::setVar('row',$comments);
parent::display($tpl);
}   
}
?>
```

and view.html of Hello2 View is

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die( 'Restricted access' );
jimport( 'joomla.application.component.view');
jimport('joomla.environment.request');

class Hello2ViewHello2 extends JView{

function display($tpl = null) 
    {
    $model = &$this->getModel(); 
    $comments = $model->getComments();
    JRequest::setVar('rows',$comments);
    parent::display($tpl);

if($this->getLayout() == 'view') {
        $this->view($tpl);
        return;
    }
   }
  }
  ?>
```

It works for me to execute `index.php?option=com_hello2&task=display`
but gets error when execute `index.php?option=com_hello2&task=view`
eventhough the default.php is already inside the directory views/viewed/ 
any input appreciated! :)

Comment: I suspect the problem is caused because I used 'view' as the task. I added 'a' to the 'view' and boom! Joomla finally told me not to use 'view' as name as it may collide with its core coding. I changed the task, model name, and the view name into 'iew', and everything goes exactly i want it to. Wow..all the trouble and confusion...it's because of the name...really?? well anyway, it seems I have finally concluded my component code and ready to move on to next step. :)

Comment: I will keep this question undeleted on stackoverflow. I hope it could help somebody else who finds similar problem with me.